# Select the last two items of a parent element, add class and apply changes to both of them->not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This jsfiddle example can explain more or less what I mean
[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/oajocuds/)

This is my actual code

JS

```
loadMore : function(){
        var limit = initial_rows+1; //initial_rows begin being 2
        var number_of_rows_to_append = initial_rows+2; // 4
        $card.css('height', $card.find('.title-box').height()  + number_of_rows_to_append * 70); //update card height
        for(var i = initial_rows; i<=limit; i++){
            $(template(content[i])).appendTo($contentJQuery);
        }
        $contentJQuery.find('.normal-box').slice(-2).addClass('show');
        initial_rows+=2;
        }
    },
```

CSS

```
    .normal-box{ /*Container of other tiny boxes*/
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-bottom-color: gainsboro;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
.normal-box.show{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="normal-box">
     </div>
     <div class="normal-box">
     </div>
     <div class="normal-box">
     </div>
     <div class="normal-box">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Basically there is a function which creates the card and appends only 2 normal-boxes at the beginning(there opacity is set to 1 automatically). When loadMore() function is triggered 2 more rows have to be appended with the opacity transition as shown in the jsfiddle example(in my case the rows appear, in the jsfiddle they disappear). The transition consists in the card getting bigger(thats why card height gets updated) with a blank space, then the 2 last normal-boxes appear with transition

The problem is that in my case the last row appears without transition and the penultimate appears with transition, no idea why. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: in your css (in the question), `normal-box.show` must be `.normal-box.show`, you are forgetting the dot at the beggining

Comment: Edited. That was just an error writing the question

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle with the same problem that yours?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle:

Perhaps this is what you intended:

[revised jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oajocuds/2/)

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text().slice(0,-2); //or .slice(-1) ?
        $(this).text(txt).addClass('change');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but no, the jsfiddle is just an example of what I want to accomplish, perhaps I didnt explain myself well :/

Comment: Looking at your code, you should still be able to fix your problem by implementing the solution above. *Best of luck with your project*